# 落としちまった - what form is this?

Tags: grammar, verbs, て-form, contractions, subsidiary-verbs

The phrase is pretty simple:

> デスノート
>   落{お}としちまった

Which is obviously, "I dropped my Death Note".

The verb (and the kanji) is for おとす or おちる, which is "to drop" or "to let fall", yet this is a verbal form that I couldn't find anywhere. It looks like a mix between the two verbs. I can't really tell what to make of it grammatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It *is* two verbs. You just had the two wrong verbs in mind.

落｛お｝としちまった
is the colloquial form of 落｛お｝としてしまった, which in turn is comprised of the following two verbs:

落｛お｝として (て form): [落とす (jisho.org)](http://jisho.org/word/%E8%90%BD%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99)

しまった (past form): [しまう (jisho.org)](http://jisho.org/word/%E4%BB%95%E8%88%9E%E3%81%86)

By slurring the pronunciation of てし, you end up with ち, hence 落｛お｝とし**てし**まった→ 落｛お｝とし**ち**まった

ちまう has its own dictionary entry here: [ちまう (jisho.org)](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%A1%E3%81%BE%E3%81%86)

Comment: Formally it would be a contraction 落としてしまった where 〜てしまった is replaced with ちまった.

Answer (score 0):

「落としちまった」is a colloquial form of 「落としてしまいました」